# remove spaces from start of variable batch

Tags: batch-file

i'm doing some maintenence script and want to get defragment status like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
defrag c: -a>%TEMP%\defrag_c_fixed.txt
for /f "skip=4 delims=,(  tokens=4" %%a in (%TEMP%\defrag_c_fixed.txt) do set fragment=%%a
for /f "skip=5 tokens=*" %%a in (%TEMP%\defrag_c_fixed.txt) do set recommend=%%a
echo !fragment!
echo !recommend!
pause
```

I'm getting fragment status with spaces in the start of the numbers:

```
  20% Fragmented
You should defragment this volume.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can i delete this from script?

Comment: That's the output format of the `defrag` command. Suit yourself with it.

Comment: yes Rahul that's very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FOR /F to strip leading spaces. Using TOKENS=* will strip leadiing delimiters, and the default delimiters are space and tab.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ("!fragment!") do echo(%%A
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

for 1 space:

```
echo !fragment:~1!
```

Comment: tha's nice and I thought to try it but the spaces are dynamic